# SQLite and ICSharp.ZipLib is giving errors during build app in release mode

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, marketplace, release-mode, icsharpcode

i am working on windows phone 8 app. I am facing following errors, you can see the name of dlls in mentioned messages which are working in debug mode. But when i am building my app in release mode than these errors are coming. any idea ?

1)The type or namespace name 'ICSharpCode' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

2)The type or namespace name 'Community' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: try re adding the same in release mode(by removing and re referencing), This worked for me

Comment: With the help your suggession my first error has been resolved, and same way i tried with the SQLite but it is not helping with sqlite.